# SQL query for list category & subcategory

Tags: mysql, sql, e-commerce, categories, product

This category/subcategory table for eCommerce site.
The level of subcategory are unlimited that admin can create many level subcategories.

[image]

Output
Books
Books>English
Books>English>Quotes

Stationary
Stationary>Paper
Stationary>Paper>Art
Stationary>Paper>Art>Cover
Stationary>Paper>Art>Cover>A4 Size

Suggest me the SQL query to display output as below:

Comment: It's almost impossible to do in pure SQL.  You can use mySQL functions, but generally, you'd be better off to use an application server to parse the results from a DB call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the approach with `parent_id` you cannot have a MySql-Query with unlimited subcategories because MySql doesn't support recursion.
You have to do this with serverside programming.

I would suggest to read about [nested sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) or [closure tables](http://karwin.blogspot.de/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html).

With these approaches you will be able to get all tree levels with one query.

Comment: another useful link : http://mirror.neu.edu.cn/mysql/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html

Comment: @VillRaj link expired

Comment: **Third and Forth** level of category can be done using Product Tags, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5384967/2218697) am i right ?