# how do i design schema for categories in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, categories

I am writing this web app for posts,links . Users will be abe to add categories to these links/posts . The number of these categories will increase as the website grows bigger. how do I  implement this in SQL schema ? what datatype should I use? and is TEXT datatype a good way to store user posts?

Comment: What language are you writing your app in?  My suggestion is you do a little research on 'tags' because I know there's a lot of work done in how you set them up etc...and that's really what you're setting up.

Comment: Either `TEXT` or `VARCHAR` should work for posts (both having a max limit of 65KB in MySQL 5.0 and later).

Comment: i am gonna use golang.

Comment: This is a standard example in many books, tutorials and examples on SQL or MySQL. Please query at least google, then you would find something like this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384183/database-design-question-categories-subcategories or this http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ blog post. Please ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the *first* thing that you should do is to surf GitHub and other places for existing work that already does this. *(Maybe you can simply **use** something that has already been written!)*

Theoretically speaking: the relationship between "links/posts" and "categories" is called *many-to-many.* (A link/post may have "many" attributes, and a given attribute may be assigned to "many" links/posts.) Therefore, an intermediate table is used, as in the following trivial example:

```
CREATE TABLE LINKS_POSTS ( LINK_ID INTEGER, CONTENT TEXT) PRIMARY KEY (LINK_ID);

CREATE TABLE ATTRIBS ( ATTRIB_ID INTEGER, ATTRIB_NAME TEXT) PRIMARY KEY (ATTRIB_ID);
```

and now the magic ...

```
    CREATE TABLE LINKS_POSTS_ATTRIBS ( LPA_ID INTEGER, LINK_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
ATTRIB_ID INTEGER NOT NULL ) PRIMARY KEY (LPA_ID) 
FOREIGN KEY (LINK_ID) REFERENCES LINKS_POSTS (LINK_ID) 
FOREIGN KEY (ATTRIB_ID) REFERENCES ATTRIBS (ATTRIB_ID);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX FOOBAR ON LINKS_POSTS_ATTRIBS(LINK_ID, ATTRIB_ID);
```

... (or something like that!) I'm writing this off the top of my head, so there might be tpyos or sintax erurs. ;-)

When a given post has a particular attribute, an entry in the `LINKS_POSTS_ATTRIBS` table represents it. The `FOREIGN KEY` attribute stipulates that the values must match an existing entry in the foreign table. The `UNIQUE INDEX` avoids duplicates.

Further "referential integrity" constraints should be used as necessary to stipulate, for example, that an attribute-row may not be removed if any `LINKS_POSTS_ATTRIBS` entries refer to it.