# want to view ids from column with more than one value

Tags: php, mysql

I have table contains "category" column which contains more than one value separated by ","

example :

> user_ID --- "1" **|** category --- "video, audio, games"
>
> user_ID --- "2" **|** category --- "audio, write"
>
> user_ID --- "3" **|** category --- "video, games"

Now I explode category column by :

```
$data = explode(',', $get_category_section);
```

so I get array ..

Now I want to view ID of each category

example

> category audio will show user_id "1" and "2"
>
> category video will show user_id "1" and "3"

and so on

This is my code - I know it miss so much :

```
    if (isset($_GET['category']) === true and empty($_GET['category']) === false) {
        $get_category = $_GET['category'];
        global $connect;
        $query = "SELECT category FROM `users`";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die('erreor');
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $get_category_section = $row['category'];


    $data = explode(',', $get_category_section);
    $category_array = in_array($get_category, $data);

    echo //

     }

    }
```

and my url is : http://localhost/site/get_categories.php?category=video

I want this page to show 1 and 3

Thanks

Comment: Either normalise your schema or don't bother with an RDBMS.

Comment: if its not too late change db design  .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384183/database-design-question-categories-subcategories

Comment: I have over 66 categories .. it's hard to normalize it

Comment: It's easier than you think to normalize it - if you understand what is meant by normalize. You would create a new table called categories with one row per category and an ID column (int autoincrement primary key). Then create another table that has two columns, one for the ID to your existing table, and another to the categories table. This provides a many-to-many relationship. You might try searching for many-to-many relations for more info.

Comment: If you can't do that (then whats the point of using a RDBMS), you can always just use a LIKE statement in your where clause: ```WHERE `category` LIKE '%video&' ``` or similar. Not efficient, and not as maintainable as using a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: One more point: How are we supposed to see your page?

Comment: just for viewing link to get my idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely you should go towards normalising or refactoring your db design even with 66 categories(they are not many). Create a separate table for categories and create another table for storing user_id and category_id.

If you still want to continue with the same structure, here are the possible solutions with your existing schema..

Solution 1:

```
$param = "%{$_GET['category']}%";
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE category LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $param);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

while ($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf("User Ids are: %s\n", $myrow['user_id']);
}
```

Please run explain on the query as 'like' may be slow

Solution 2:

```
$param = "%{$_GET['category']}%";
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT user_id, category FROM users");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

while ($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    unset($caregories);
    $categories = explode(",", $myrow['category']);
    if(in_array($param, $categories)) {
            $user_id[] = $myrow['user_id'];
        }
   }
```

The user_ids will be in array user_id. Please note that this will become slow as number of records in the table increase.

Comment: If I do normalize database I will have a problem that each time user update his category it will insert new row in "user_id and category_id" table

Comment: Even now user must be updating categories and you must be updating the table. Where do you see problem with the insert? I don't know the use case but one solution can be to delete all the records for user categories and insert the updated ones....however, with this history won't be saved.

Comment: Ok i get it .. Thanks alot :)

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if you went with it...or upvote..Thanks